# Redirect output to mulitple files with tee and grep

Tags: shell, logging, grep, tee

I spent a lot of hours to get this to run:

redirecting output from a script STDOUT + STDERR toLogfile 1 and a grep to Logfile 2

The First logfile should contain the complete output, and the second logfile only Start and End-Lines (grep).

I tried different syntax, but nothing works.

```
./run.sh 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/log1.log | (grep 'START|END') > /var/log/myscripts.log

./run.sh 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/log1.log | grep 'Start' > /var/log/myscripts.log

./run.sh 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/log1.log | egrep 'Start' > /var/log/myscripts.log

./run.sh 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/log1.log | grep -E 'Start' > /var/log/myscripts.log
```

the output will be redirected only to the first log. The second log is empty.

I don't know why; do you have any ideas?

Example-Lines from Output

this should be complete in the log1.log

(the script is java startet via shell script)

```
26.09.2014 20:38:51 |       start script > load_stats.sh
26.09.2014 20:38:51 | [DB DATA]         
26.09.2014 20:38:51 |               Host > locahost
26.09.2014 20:38:51 |               User > leroy

... more ...

26.09.2014 20:39:23 |         fin script > load_stats.sh
```

I want to grep this in myscripts.log

```
26.09.2014 20:38:51 |       start script > load_stats.sh
26.09.2014 20:39:23 |         fin script > load_stats.sh
```

I think the problem is the format, timestamp, whitespaces.
I thought grep 'word' will catch me this both lines, but it doesn't.
Stupid.

```
./run.sh 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/log1.log | sed -nE '/(start script|end script)/p' >> /var/log/myscripts.log
```

did not work, log1 ok, mysrctips.log empty

```
tail -f -n 500 /var/log/log1.log | sed -nE '/(start script|end script)/p'
```

works well in the shell. but in combination of all it doesn't.

execute a script > redirect to log 1 > redirect and filter(grep,egrep,sed,..) to log 2

Comment: you grepping different words, once `START` next time `Start` - so, what you want grep?

Comment: 'START|END' are Text-Patterns. I like to grep "Start Script" and "Fin Script".

Comment: i tried the sysntax and the same happens. But know i think the problem is another.

Comment: sorry "Main-Job" was a line from debugging. start and end are 'star script' and 'end script'

Comment: sorry, for changing the text. i tried to append, but i have to cut personalize data out of the lines, therefore i must edit the lines later

Comment: ~/log1.log or /var/log/log1.log makes no difference. the files in the home directoy are symlinks to /var/log

Comment: I hope you can see over the little grammar and punctuation mistakes, but i'm out of practice with englisch

Comment: Sorry, but nothing works. I've got many and fast replies, i tried all, but the second log did not work. I've the same situation before i wrote this question.

Comment: Maybe you need the `-i` (case-insensitive) option to `grep`.  The other thing to bear in mind is that in a pipeline, the output may be buffered, so nothing gets written by `grep` until enough material has accumulated to fill a buffer, and that may be 4 KiB or more these days (historically, it was often 512 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
$ cat <<_DATA | tee out1 | grep -E 'START|END' > out2
hello 
START1
foo
END2
bar
_DATA
$ cat out1
hello 
START1
foo
END2
bar
$ cat out2
START1
END2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
./run_test.sh 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/log1.log | grep -E 'start script|fin Main-Job' > /var/log/myscripts.log
#                        ^^ append              ^^^^^^^ - same as egrep             ^overwrite/create
```

prints

```
26.09.2014 20:38:51 |       start script > load_stats.sh
26.09.2014 20:39:23 |       fin Main-Job > load_stats.sh
```

if want

- overwrite/create the log1 - delete the `-a`
- append to `myscripts.log` use `>>`
- the `egrep` is deprecated - therefore is better to use `grep -E`

Also, instead of the `grep` you can use `sed` too, like:

```
sed -nE '/(start script|fin Main-Job)/p'
```